# Want to make changes in Sub Admin and their views in admin panel

Tags: admin, view

I created a one main admin account name xyz ( Full Access of all modules) and three different sub-admin user account names are xyz1, xyz2 and xyz3 and this three sub-admin have only access of only modules (Dashboard, Sales, Catalogue, Customers, and Reports).
My requirement is all three sub-admin has a separate admin panel of the module of because all three sub-admins are sited in three different our country offices. 
So, obliviously they are individual sales, customers, and products and they are not interrelated to each other. 
Our aim is to make the separate view of backend admin for all three sub-admins. E.g. xyz has a separate admin panel view and he can’t see either xyz1 & xyz2 admin panel & vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

In Magento add new role with "**Resource Access**" and assign to admin user:

**GoTo :**
Magento admin -> Permissions -> Roles -> create new roles -> got to "Role Resources" -> set "Resource Access" as you want to show of other admin

**GoTo :**
Magento admin -> Permissions -> Users -> sub-admin-user -> User Role -> Assign your new roles

Comment: Hello Sir,Thanks for your reply but there is still one problem and that is sub admin1 can see the details of sub admin2 if admin gives same module access to both sub admins 1 & 2.lets say admin gives "customer" or "dashboard" module access to both admins so i want each sub admin should get their own details like daily sell or customers under him.So if you have any solutions for this please let me know sir